# Conversion from Visual* to GdkVisual*

Tags: x11, gdk

I can do vice-versa using below api

```
Visual *gdk_x11_visual_get_xvisual (GdkVisual *visual);
```

but i don't find any api which can provide me GdkVisual* out of Visual*

Comment: Use gdk_x11_screen_lookup_visual with visual ID from visual via XVisualIDFromVisual

Comment: Thanks @n.m. this is what i was looking for. Any idea to set particular GdkVisual from configuration file rather then coding?

Comment: No idea, it would probably be the wrong thing to do. An app should always find an appropriate visual dynamically, or just use the default one if it doesn't care. Setting e.g. a visual id in a config file means you are now tied to your particular x11 configuration and may have to edit your config with any change to x11, probably even when attaching a different monitor.